# iPad is unresponsive

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm currently developing an iOS application. The problem is the iPad 2 I'm using for the testing runs it really slowly. The pushes and pops are slow, the lists are unresponsive, etc.

I tried to isolate one View Controller with only one UITableViewController to find out the reason for the unresponsiveness. The application was still slow.

After that, I commented the webservice call and the parsing call, leaving the application with only one UITableView, showing 30 rows of static text. Still slow.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:identifier];


    UILabel *labelTeamA = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [labelTeamA setText:@"test"];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}
```

Other applications already installed run fine.

Please, help me finding out the problem.

**Edit:**
Just found that the libGoogleAdMobAds.a library was responsible for all the lag in the application. Is there any solution?

Comment: Application empty with only a table view? Should be perfectly fine. Can You maybe try restarting iPad?

Comment: Just did it, still slow...

Comment: Could it be your iPad is out of disk space? Check Settings->General->Usage for this.

Comment: Which iOS SDK are you targeting and which OS is installed on the iPad?

Comment: @gWiz Storage is 11,6 GB Available and 2,0 GB Used.

Comment: @Romain I'm targeting 7.0 and I the iPad is running version 7.0.6

Comment: I think you should wait for iOS 7.1 for a good performance, or you can make a clean restore your backup and it will by way faster.

Comment: Why is it fast running other applications then?

Comment: Could you try to deploy a brand new app using Xcode's default "Master-detail" application template, with no further modification, and see if it's equally slow?

Comment: @Romain I just deployed a brand new app with a single view and with the same code as before (just UITableView with 30 cells) and the list is fast and responsive... I don't understand.

Comment: There's probably something you forgot in your previous app, a test or something you don't remember is there, but *is* there :) Maybe you could try to start this app with Instruments and see where all this CPU or memory hog comes from?

Comment: Edit: Just found that the libGoogleAdMobAds.a library was responsible for all the lag in the application. Is there any solution?